# Screen get state or attach and detach in one line

Tags: unix, gnu-screen

I'm running a lot of detached programs simultaneously with `screen`. Each of these program output (`cout` C++) their current progression (from 0 to 100, 100 meaning that they are completed). It would be easier for me if I could write a Python script which lists the detached screen sessions, then attaches and detaches them one by one, reading the progression and then outputting it all to me.

I can see how to do everything but the attach/detach part. Or is there a parameter in `screen` that would just return the current window?

Sorry if this sounds confusing, please don't hesitate asking me clarifications.

Comment: Do you have multiple windows, multiple screen sessions, or both? Parsing the output of `screen -ls` seems like an obvious first step.

Comment: Multiple screen sessions Yes, multiple windows I'm not sure what you mean :/
And I already have a script scanning with `screen -ls` and listing me all the detached sessions. Id like to go further than that now.

Comment: Each screen session can have multiple windows, listed from within the screen session by Ctrl-A " (if Ctrl-A is your escape character). Do you have, and are you trying to track, multiple windows within each screen session, or does each of your Python scripts run as the only window within a screen session? Are your scripts interactive? If not, I'm not sure what screen does for you. Why not just run each script in the background with stdout redirected to a file, and keep track of the PID and output file for each instance of the script?

Comment: No I don't use multiple windows, I use screen to be able to detach and reattach to a totally different bash session, through network and another computer. Your idea seems to work though I doubt it's the best solution in my case, I'm afraid I'll be storing quickly more and more scratch files among important data files.

Comment: If management of multiple files per instance is the issue, just give each instance its own directory, perhaps with a name determined by the process id. `screen` is great for interactive programs. Using it for what seem to be essentially batch programs, and particularly using a distinct screen session (as opposed to window) for each one feels (to me) like overkill. I suspect you have an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Well, thank you for the reference, I didn't know about these XY problems and maybe indeed am I falling into one. I'll think about implementing your solution. I was reticent at the idea of changing code that already runs instead of working on a script. Thank you for the input Keith ;)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are already going to be using a script to monitor, would it not be far easier to just launch them via python and pipe the output?

This could rather easily be done via the `subprocess` module from the default Python library.

Comment: Can I 'cut' this pipe? In the sense, do I need to have this Python script running for my programs to be running? Or can I close the script and 'reattach' the pipe just like screen does? (I have programs running for days/weeks and it would be difficult to stay connected non-stop whilst running).

Comment: @Learningisamess Using this method, the Python script would launch all the programs itself, and they would remain attached to the Python script.  So yes, the script would have to remain running.  It is effectively acting as a "custom" screen that can watch the programs like you wanted.

Comment: @Learningisamess I posted another answer that'll show you the code necessary to do what I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

This is one method you could use instead of screen.  It reads a list of all the programs you need to run from a file you pass as a command line argument.

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess
import threading
from queue import Queue
import time

lock = threading.Lock()
q = Queue()

def do_work(item):
    while True:
            line = item.stdout.readline().strip()

            if line == "":
                break
            elif line == "100":
                with lock:
                    print("Child process is a success.")

def worker():
    item = q.get()
    do_work(item)
    q.task_done()

def get_programs(filename):
    input = open(filename, "r")
    programs = []

    counter = 1

    for line in input:
        line = line.strip()
        if line.startswith(";"):
            continue
        if len(line) == 0:
            continue

        program = line.split(" ")

        if not os.path.exists(program[0]):
            print("ERROR: \"%s\" at line %s does not exist." % (program[0], counter))
            continue

        programs.append(program)

        counter += 1

    return programs

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) < 2 or not os.path.exists(sys.argv[1]):
        print("Please provide a valid program config file.")
        sys.exit()

    programs = get_programs(sys.argv[1])
    print("Loaded %s entries from \"%s\"." % (len(programs), sys.argv[1]))

    for program in programs:
        s = subprocess.Popen(program, shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True)
        q.put(s)
        t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()

    q.join()
    print("All tasks are done.")
```

Hope this helps, lemme know if you need any modifications, and good luck!